# A good way to implement a REST API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest

We've to implement a REST API to access some features of our current server, which is written in C#. So, we'd like to expose some of its functionality (currently done through TCP) using a REST API.

Can you post some pointers to the right docs and ideas about how to get it implemented?

The server is not a "aspx" server but a service app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft's MSDN contains [information on how to create RESTful services with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529).

Comment: Out dated and old page. Oh, see they updated it. Couple of monthes ago, there was still a REST Starter Kit

Answer (score 2):

For now primary REST technology in Microsoft stack is ASP.NET Web API http://www.asp.net/web-api (former WCF Web API)

Visit web site for ASP.NET Web API, there are a lot of tutorials on how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend to take a look at my [different REST approach](https://restafar.com/create-new-rest-server/).

- Don't use nested complex paths, keep it simple flat list of services and actions.
- Don't use custom HTTP methods, use the path to specify the action.
- Don't use custom HTTP error codes, that will mix your applicative errors with the HTTP protocol errors and will prevent complex error codes or partial success.
- Support multi-request, which is multiple applicative requests in each HTTP request.

I also introduce simple [C# simple REST server example](https://restafar.com/c-very-simple-rest-server/) for your convenience.

Answer (score -1):

I have worked with a REST API in a project:

> [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)is a simple, open source REST client for .NET designed primarily for consuming third-party HTTP APIs.

It took a lot of work out of my hands - i don't want to miss it ;-)

The Author of the Library John Sheehan is also on StackOverflow and usually helps really fast with specific problems!

Comment: Ok, but AFAIK this is useful to create clients... I need a server :)